# django holding onto files in cache, delete view.py and view.pyc file, still runs

Tags: python, linux, django, nginx

I've inherited a project which is a site running python/django. Having an issue where I believe Django is holding onto files in memcache (possibly).

It's a production server. There is currently no DEV environment (this is another matter).

I'm forced to make a requested emergency bug fix to the live site. BUT any modification to .py files are not reflected on the site. I can even delete a view.py (and view.pyc) entirely and the page merrily continues to load. I have looked into caching (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/cache/), and have added the appropriate dummycache line:

```
CACHES = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.dummy.DummyCache',
    }
}
```

I've  tried forcing cache to 1 second:

```
CACHE_MIDDLEWARE_KEY_PREFIX = ''
CACHE_MIDDLEWARE_SECONDS = 1
CACHE_MIDDLEWARE_ALIAS = 'default'
```

Restarting nginx service does not help. I can run `/etc/init.d/nginx restart` and original files are still running after changes or being deleted completely. The only thing which forces the new files to be read and re-compiled to pyc is restarting the entire VPS instance! I can edit templates just fine and changes are reflected asap, its only py files not compiling to pyc.

Some other points:

1. I've also tried `sudo /etc/init.d/nginx reload`, no dice.
2. This is an AWS EC2 linux VPS its running python via nginx not apache
3. I've tried `touch <project>/wsgi.py`
4. Distro is CentOS release 6.5 (Final), so i've also tried `sudo service nginx reload` and `sudo service nginx restart`.

Is anyone please able to shed some light on this?

Edit: as a test, I've just deleted a critical view.py + view.pyc file to a sub section of the site, after 15 minutes, it is still running perfectly.

Edit2: i'm starting to think I'm simply meant to restart nginx in a different way. What should I be calling? [Saving Changes To Django with Nginx?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25335912/saving-changes-to-django-with-nginx?rq=1)

Edit3: Based on IgnacioVazquez-Abrams help below, found that it was using uwsgi via ps -ef processes. I then found that it was using supervisor as a manager and all appropriate conf files looked fine. Then simply had to restart supervisor and BAM files updated instantly. Needless to say, this was stretching my knowledge of linux + python.

Comment: How are you running the Django project?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams, sorry I'm not sure what you mean by how am I running it. But its served from a linux VPS. Its running on python running via nginx proxy. I'm modifying files both via terminal directly (incase any issue with timestamps) and remotely via a pycharm project.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams, oh also, i'm running the site via web browser. Firefox & chrome

Comment: Are you using CGI? FastCGI? uWSGI?

Comment: the project has a wsgi.py file, so possibly uWSGI

Comment: Digging up how it's working will solve this for you.

Comment: hmm that helps, I'm trying to determine which server its running. Hopefully I can figure it out, cheers

Comment: ok after running `ps -ef | grep "sgi"` i found there were uwsgi processes running. I then found the /conf/uwsgi file. so I'm fairly certain its running that as a server. Still trying to figure out how to restart it.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams, OMG! I got it. Ok... so your implying that I should look into what is loading django was just what i needed. I found that it was using uwsgi via ps -ef processes. I then found that it was using supervisor as a manager and all appropriate conf files looked fine. Then simply had to restart supervisor and BAM files updated instantly. It begs the question though, is there not an easier way to have files auto reload after a specified period or time, or is this crucial to improved performance of the python/django/nginx/uwsgi stack? Anyway words cannot express how elated i am

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on IgnacioVazquez-Abrams help, found that `nginx` was using `uwsgi` to serve django, via ps -ef processes. After finding it was using uwsgi, and finding the uwsgi conf file i did a `ack` search for any references to loading the uwsgi file which found it in the supervisor conf file.

I then found that it was using `supervisor` as a manager and all appropriate conf files looked fine. Then simply had to restart `supervisor` and BAM files updated instantly. Needless to say, this was stretching my knowledge of linux + python.

It begs the question though, is there not an easier way to have files auto reload after a specified period or time, or is this crucial to improved performance of the python/django/nginx/uwsgi stack?